# Kafka Admin Client Consumer Group states

Tags: java, apache-kafka

The Kafka Admin client has apis that can produce details of Consumer Groups. One such detail is [Consumer State](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/ConsumerGroupState.html). Below are the states mentioned in the apis, with no documentation.

Apart from Rebalancing, i can not figure out what the other states relate to. Does anyone have any idea or documentation somewhere which provides any information about what these states mean and how kafka assigns them to consumer groups?

[image]

Comment: Regarding "how" - have you searched the Kafka source code?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I tried, but a lot is going on there and i could not find any logic as such where state is being assigned

Comment: What exactly do you need this information for? As far as I know, these enums are only exposed via logging, and not the AdminClient. But to answer part of the question - Stable comes after competing and completing after preparing. Dead and Empty are for when there are no consumers in the group and Unknown is a default for when none of the others can be found.

Comment: @OneCricketeer these enums are exposed via admin client apis. I need the information because i need to programatically delete consumer groups not in use

Comment: Consumer groups are automatically deleted over time and having idle ones isn't a problem. You could also just list them all, loop, then describe, then check if there are active members without any of these enums

Comment: That same describe api provides these enum states as well. Also, sometimes it does not show any members, when this is not really the case for that consumer group. @OneCricketeer

Comment: Okay, well, like I said, you should try filtering for DEAD/EMPTY/UNKNOWN, and you can try to delete those (or, just let the groups automatically get deleted)